# How to auto-complete variable names of Sass using ST3? (probable package conflicts)

Tags: html, ubuntu, sublimetext3, compass-sass

I am using Compass with H5BP, developing with Sublime Text 3.
I've set up some variables and I want to use an autocomplete feature when typing them.

Also, I think I've installed **a lot** packages for *auto-complete/code completion/code assistance*, could you please tell me if there are any conflicts, or if there are some that can be removed(without loosing functionality)?

These are the ones I've installed:

- All Autocomplete
- Bracket Highlighter
- Emmet
- Hayaku
- HTML5
- LiveReload
- Sass
- Sublime CodeIntel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **SASS Snippets.** It lets me auto complete variable names.